# Magento 1.9 - Where is Sales Email option

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, sales

I have created a custom email template for Order Confirmation email.
Now I want to select that template in the admin so it can be the template/design which will be send to customers who place orders.
What I know is I have to select that template from Sales > Sales Emails ...
But I didn't find 'Sales Emails' option under System > Configuration > Sales.

Please guide me the correct path where I can apply my new custom template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add your custom template in `System > Transactional Emails`.

Then you can select your custom template in

> System > Configuration >  Sales > SalesEmails

Under `Order` select `New Order Confirmation Template`. The Template you added will be available in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You can change from **`Admin -> Sales -> Sales email`**

Here 
http://prntscr.com/lwvdld